# Nutritional tables API recommendation

Tags: api, rest

I am looking for API where I can get nutritional tables for food products. No recipes,  no prepared food of various brands(like cans, instant noodles, snacks etc..). I need just simple data about basic ingredients.
Example:

> product : barley flakes, amount : 100 unit : g, kcal : 370, carbs : 70,
>   protein : 11, fat : 3
>
> product : red lentil, amount : 100, unit : g, kcal : 230, carbs : 40,
>   protein : 18, fat : 0.8
>
> product : milk 3.2, amount : 100, unit : ml, kcal : 50, carbs : 5, protein
>   : 3.1, fat : 1
>
> product : chicken breast, amount : 100, unit : g, kcal : 164, carbs : 0,
>   protein : 31, fat : 3.8

Comment: This is a question for [Opendata.SE], but **search that site first**, because I think questions like these have already been answered there.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite catalog of public APIs is [ProgrammableWeb](https://www.programmableweb.com/)

Doing a quick search there, here are some APIs that might cater to your needs:

- [Nutritionix](https://developer.nutritionix.com/docs/v1_1)
- [ESHA Nutrition Database](http://developer.esha.com/docs/read/Home)
- [CS50](https://cs50.3scale.net/docs)

If these aren't what you need, you can search the ProgrammableWeb site yourself for your specific requirements.

Comment: Also, be aware of our [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) sister site